# Cannot convert the "System.Reflection.Missing" value of type "System.Reflection.Missing" to type "System.Int32". - PowerShell PPT Printing

Tags: powershell, powerpoint

I'm trying to put in default/null/missing values for `.printout` in PowerPoint but I can't get it to work. [The value's that are giving me troubles are defined as integers in this page.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.presentation.printout)

Usually I have been able to use `[System.Type]::Missing` or `''` but neither of those work and I get the following:

```
Cannot convert the "System.Reflection.Missing" value of type "System.Reflection.Missing" to type "System.Int32".
```

How can I put in null values for those two params of `.printout` for PowerPoint?

Here is what I have for code so far:

```
###PPT
IF ($FILETYPE -eq "PPT") {
 ECHO "PPT_FOUND"

 $msoFalse = [Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState]::msoFalse
 $msoTrue = [Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState]::msoTrue

 $ObjPPT = New-Object -comobject PowerPoint.Application
 $ObjPPT.Visible  = $msoTrue
 #$ObjPPT.DisplayAlerts = $msoFalse 
 #Exception setting "DisplayAlerts": "Cannot convert value "msoFalse" to type "Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.PpAlertLevel" due to enumeration values that are not valid. Specify one of the following 
 #enumeration values and try again. The possible enumeration values are "ppAlertsNone,ppAlertsAll"."
 
 #.Open
 $FILENAME = $FILEPATH
 IF (!$ReadOnly){$ReadOnly = $msoTrue}
 IF (!$Untitled){$Untitled = $missing}
 IF ((!$WithWindow) -and ($OPENUI -eq "FALSE")){$WithWindow = $msoFalse} ELSE {$WithWindow = $msoTrue}
 $ObjPresentation=$ObjPPT.Presentations.open($FILENAME,$ReadOnly,$Untitled,$WithWindow)

 #.Print
 #.PrintOut (From[Integer], To[Integer], PrintToFile[String], Copies [Integer], Collate[Bool]{msoTrue/False}) 
 IF (!$From){[int]$From = $missing}
 IF (!$To){[int]$To = $missing}
 IF (!$PrintToFile){[string]$PrintToFile = $missing}
 #Copies Defined Earlier
 IF (!$Collate){$Collate = $msoTrue}
 #$ObjPresentation.printout($From,$To,$PrintToFile,$COPIES,$Collate)
 $ObjPresentation.printout($From,$To)# , ,$COPIES,$Collate)

 #All Done
 Sleep 2
 $ObjPresentation.Close()
 $ObjPPT.Quit()
 Do-CloseIfRunning -Process $PROCESS
}

[gc]::collect()
[gc]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()

#Get-Variable
#PAUSE
```

Comment: Have you tried `0` or perhaps `-1`?

Comment: I think I tried 0 but not -1 will try now!

Comment: didn't throw any err for `-1`, now for a actual print test!

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen soo, `-1` worked perfectly, do you want to write up an answer?

Comment: You could possibly also do ```$ObjPPT.DisplayAlerts = [int32] $msoTrue``` if you wanted to avoid magical numbers like ```-1``` in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out using `0` caused an error, but using `-1` for `From/To` values worked as expected (null values).

Comment: I continued to receive errors though and decided to just use `.printout()`. I was able to get it to work with all params as default for Word/XLS but not PPT.